# move_base problem

Tags: navigation, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @all,
I am still having a problem with our custom 4-wheel robot. I can move it with keyboard or ArbotixGUI an create a map, that's fine. With move_base started with launchfile and after click on 2D Nav Goal in RVIZ nothing happened. With additional started amcl node in rviz I see the computed route (blue and red) but the movement goes in wrong direction backwards.

Here my files. Maybe somebody can look over and may see an error.
If you need more information or other files, please let me know.

Thank yo for your help

Michael

The robot: `fh_base_control.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Stand 27.05.2013 mha

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('fh_basecontroller')
import rospy
import tf
import math
from math import sin, cos, pi
import sys
import os
import time

from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion, Twist, Point, Pose, Pose2D, PoseWithCovariance, TwistWithCovariance, Vector3
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from EposManager.msg import MotorInfo
from EposManager.msg import EPOSControl
import dynamic_reconfigure.server



class FH_Basectrl(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        
        rospy.init_node('fh_basecontrol')
        rospy.loginfo("Init fh_basecontrol")
        
        # get values from conmon.launch
        self.ticks_per_meter = float(rospy.get_param("~ticks_per_meter", 1771))
        self.wheel_track = float(rospy.get_param("~wheel_track", 0.445))    # Distance of wheels, (Spurbreite)
        self.rate = float(rospy.get_param("~rate", 10))
        self.odom_angular_scale_correction = float(rospy.get_param("~odom_angular_scale_correction", 0.72))
        self.odom_linear_scale_correction = float(rospy.get_param("~odom_linear_scale_correction", 1))
        self.speed_factor = float(rospy.get_param("~speed_factor", 4000))   # for Eposmanager
        self.odom_frame = rospy.get_param("~odom_frame", "odom")
        self.base_frame = rospy.get_param("~base_frame", "base_link")
        
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        self.timeold = now
        self.t_delta = rospy.Duration(1.0 / self.rate)
        self.t_next = now + self.t_delta
        self.then = now # time for determining dx/dy
        
        # reset on start
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.theta = 0
        self.d_left = 0.0
        self.d_right = 0.0
        self.motor_position_left_old = 0
        self.motor_position_right_old = 0
        self.motor_position_left_new = 0
        self.motor_position_right_new = 0
        
        self.init = 1   # init counter: first Motor_Infos will be trashed
        self.waitforMotor_Infos = 0     # wait untill Motor_infos from both motors arrived 
        
        self._pos2D  = Pose2D()   # 2D Pose for odometrie       
        
        # subscriptions
        self.cmd_vel_sub = rospy.Subscriber("cmd_vel", Twist, self._HandleVelocityCommand)
        self.motorInfoSubscriber = rospy.Subscriber("motors/Motor_Info", MotorInfo, self._motorInfoCallback)
        
        # publisher
        self._OdometryTransformBroadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        self._OdometryPublisher = rospy.Publisher("odom", Odometry)
        self._EPOSControlPublisher = rospy.Publisher("motors/Motor_Control", EPOSControl)
        
        self.joint_states_pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState)     
        

        
    def _motorInfoCallback(self,msg):
        """ Handle EPOS Motorinfo requests """
        self.now = rospy.Time.now()
        
                        

        if msg.node_id == 1:    
            self.motor_position_left_new = msg.motor_position
            self.waitforMotor_Infos|=0x01
              
        
        if msg.node_id == 2:    
            self.motor_position_right_new = msg.motor_position  
            self.waitforMotor_Infos|=0x02
             
            
        # when both msg.motor_position arrived: go ahead
        if self.waitforMotor_Infos!=0x03:
            return

        self.waitforMotor_Infos = 0
        
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        if now > self.t_next:
            dt = now - self.timeold
            dt = dt.to_sec()
            self.timeold = now
        
        # calculate odometry
        self.d_left = (self.motor_position_left_new - self.motor_position_left_old)/ self.ticks_per_meter
        self.d_right = (self.motor_position_right_new - self.motor_position_right_old)/ self.ticks_per_meter
        
        # invert the direction of one motor
        self.d_right *= -1. 
        
        self.motor_position_left_old = self.motor_position_left_new
        self.motor_position_right_old = self.motor_position_right_new 
        
        # delete first values
        if self.init > 0:
            # rospy.logwarn("####### init:" + str(self.init) )
            self.init = self.init -1
            return
                      
        dxy_ave = (self.d_left + self.d_right) / 2.0
        dtheta = (self.d_right - self.d_left) / self.wheel_track    
        
        vxy = dxy_ave  / dt
        vth = dtheta / dt
        dtheta = float(dtheta) / 100 # m --> cm
        dtheta = dtheta * self.odom_angular_scale_correction
        dxy_ave = float(dxy_ave)
        rospy.logwarn("d_theta: %s" %str(dtheta)) 
        rospy.logwarn("vth: %s" %str(vth))
        
        if (dxy_ave != 0):
            dx = cos(dtheta) * dxy_ave 
            dy = -sin(dtheta) * dxy_ave
            self.x +=((cos(self.theta) * dx - sin(self.theta) * dy) /100.) * self.odom_linear_scale_correction
            self.y +=((sin(self.theta) * -dx + cos(self.theta) * dy) /100.) * self.odom_linear_scale_correction 
        else:
            rospy.logwarn ("dxy_ave != 0")
            
        rospy.logwarn("pos x: %.2lf" %self.x)
        rospy.logwarn("pos y: %.2lf" %self.y)
        
                
        if dtheta != 0:
            self.theta = self.theta+dtheta
            
        
        quaternion = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, self.theta)
        quaternion = Quaternion()
        quaternion.x = 0.0
        quaternion.y = 0.0
        quaternion.z = sin(self.theta / 2.0)
        quaternion.w = cos(self.theta / 2.0)


        # First, we'll publish the transform from frame odom to frame base_link over tf
        # Note that sendTransform requires that 'to' is passed in before 'from' while
        # the TransformListener' lookupTransform function expects 'from' first followed by 'to'.
        try:
            self._OdometryTransformBroadcaster.sendTransform(
                (self.x, self.y, 0),
                (quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z, quaternion.w),
                rospy.Time.now(),
                "base_link",
                "odom")               
        
        except Exception,e:
            rospy.logwarn("Unexpected error1:" + str(e))#str(sys.exc_info()[0]))
        
        odometry = Odometry()
        odometry.header.frame_id = "odom"
        odometry.child_frame_id = "base_link"
        odometry.header.stamp = now
    
        odometry.pose.pose.position.x = self.x
        odometry.pose.pose.position.y = self.y
        odometry.pose.pose.position.z = 0
        odometry.pose.pose.orientation = quaternion
        odometry.twist.twist.linear.x = vxy
        odometry.twist.twist.linear.y = 0
        odometry.twist.twist.angular.z = vth

        self._OdometryPublisher.publish(odometry)
    
    def _sendmotorVelocity(self,id1,vel1):
        '''publish EPosControl msg'''
        eposctrl = EPOSControl()
        eposctrl.control_mode=EPOSControl.VELOCITY;
        eposctrl.node_id = id1;
        eposctrl.setpoint = vel1;
        rospy.loginfo(eposctrl)
        self._EPOSControlPublisher.publish(eposctrl)
        
    def _HandleVelocityCommand(self, cmd_vel):
        """ Handle movement requests. Twistmsg"""
        
        v = cmd_vel.linear.x        # m/s
        omega = cmd_vel.angular.z      # rad/s
        
        left_speed_out  = cmd_vel.linear.x - cmd_vel.angular.z * self.wheel_track/2
        right_speed_out = cmd_vel.linear.x + cmd_vel.angular.z * self.wheel_track/2
        left_speed_out = left_speed_out * self.speed_factor
        right_speed_out = -right_speed_out * self.speed_factor
        
        self._sendmotorVelocity(1,left_speed_out)
        self._sendmotorVelocity(2,right_speed_out)

        message = 's %.2f %.2f\r' % (v, omega)
        rospy.logdebug("Sending speed command message: " + message)
    
    def _HandleEposdata(self):
        rospy.loginfo(_HandleEposdata)
        data = 0
        self._BroadcastOdometryInfo(data)
            
    def Start(self):
        rospy.logdebug("Starting")
        
    def Stop(self):
        rospy.logdebug("Stopping")
        self._sendmotorVelocity(1,0)
        self._sendmotorVelocity(2,0)
        
    def spin(self):
        js = JointState(name = ["left_wheel_joint", "right_wheel_joint", "front_castor_joint", "back_castor_joint"], position=[0,0,0,0], velocity=[0,0,0,0], effort=[0,0,0,0])  
        r = rospy.Rate(self.update_rate)
        last_cmd_vel = 0, 0
        last_cmd_vel_time = rospy.get_rostime()
        last_js_time = rospy.Time(0)
        rospy.loginfo("send velocitytest")
        

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            last_time = s.header.stamp
            curr_time = rospy.get_rostime()
            js.header.stamp = curr_time + rospy.Duration(1)
            
            
            # PUBLISH STATE

        self.odom_pub.publish(odom)
        if self.publish_tf:
            self.publish_odometry_transform(odom)
            # 1hz, future-dated joint state
        if curr_time > last_js_time + rospy.Duration(1):
            self.joint_states_pub.publish(js)
            last_js_time = curr_time
    
            r.sleep()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    basectrl = FH_Basectrl()
    try:
        basectrl.Start()
    
        rospy.spin()
    
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        basectrl.Stop()
```

The launchfile:

```
<launch>

<!-- Start the Motorcontrol -->
    <param name="run_id" value="test1" />
        <env name="ROS_LOG_DIR" value="$(find EposManager)/logs" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find EposManager)/params/Left_Motor.yaml" ns="motors/Left_Motor" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find EposManager)/params/Right_Motor.yaml" ns="motors/Right_Motor" /> 
    <node name="Drive_Motors" pkg="EposManager" type="EposManager" args="Left_Motor Right_Motor" ns="motors/" output="screen"  >
        <param name="Port" value="USB0" />
        <param name="Protocol" value="USB" />
        <param name="Publish_Rate" value="10" />        
    </node>
    
<!-- Start the Laser-Node -->
    <node name="laserscanner_tcp" pkg="rotoscan_node" type="rotoscan_node" >
        <param name="connection" type="str" value="tcp" />
        <param name="host" type="str" value="192.168.60.3" />
        <param name="port" type="str" value="9008" />
        <param name="max_range" type="double" value="40." />
    </node>
    
    <!-- Static transform for the laser -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0.12 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 100" /> 
    
<!--    optional Keyboard-Control  -->
    <!--    <node name="control" pkg="drive_base_tutorial" type="drive_base" /> -->

<!-- Load the URDF/Xacro model of our robot -->
   <arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find fh_basecontroller)/urdf/conmon.urdf.xacro'" />
        <param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />
        
<!-- Run the map server with a map -->  
        <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find fh_basecontroller)/maps/map.yaml"/> 
  
<!-- Start the Basecontroller with Parameters  -->
    <node name="basecontroller" pkg="fh_basecontroller" type="fh_base_control.py">
        <param name="odom_linear_scale_correction" value="1.0"  />  # ueber calibrate_linear.py ermittelt
        <param name="odom_angular_scale_correction" value="0.72"  /> # ueber calibrate_angular.py ermittelt
        <param name="ticks_per_meter" value="1771"  />
        <param name="wheel_track" value="0.445"  />
        <param name="rate" value="30"  />
        <param name="update_rate" value="30"  />    
        <param name="speed_factor" value = "4000" />
        <param name="cmd_vel_timeout" value = "0.6" />
        <param name="odom_frame" value = "odom" />
        <param name="base_frame" value = "base_link" />
        <param name="min_abs_yaw_vel" value = "None" />
        <param name="max_abs_yaw_vel" value = "None" />
    </node>
    
<!-- Start the move_base-node   -->
    <node name="move_base" pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find fh_basecontroller)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find fh_basecontroller)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find fh_basecontroller)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"  />
        <rosparam file="$(find fh_basecontroller)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find fh_basecontroller)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />e
    </node>
    
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_map_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom  100" />

<!-- Start the GUI to reconfigure several settings -->  
    <node name="dynamic_reconfigure" pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="reconfigure_gui" />

    <node name="robot_tf_publisher" pkg="conmon_tf" type="tf_broadcaster" />
    <node name="robot_tf_listener" pkg="conmon_tf" type="tf_listener" />

    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="10.0" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

rostopic list:

```
/cmd_vel
/initialpose
/joint_states
/map
/map_metadata
/motors/Group_Motor_Control
/motors/Group_Motor_Info
/motors/Left_Motor/parameter_descriptions
/motors/Left_Motor/parameter_updates
/motors/Motor_Control
/motors/Motor_Info
/motors/Right_Motor/parameter_descriptions
/motors/Right_Motor/parameter_updates
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/NavfnROS/plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_updates
/move_base/cancel
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/feedback
/move_base/global_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/global_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/goal
/move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space                                                                                                   
/move_base/parameter_descriptions                                                                                                        
/move_base/parameter_updates                                                                                                             
/move_base/result                                                                                                                        
/move_base/status                                                                                                                        
/move_base_simple/goal
/odom
/particlecloud
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/waypoint_markers
/waypoint_markers_array
```

rostopic echo tf:

```
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1370251675
        nsecs: 719868000
      frame_id: /map
    child_frame_id: /odom
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.012765523603
        y: -0.00185758867047
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: -0.0
        y: -0.0
        z: 8.56034512309e-05
        w: 0.999999996336
```

rostopic echo odom:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 2467
  stamp: 
    secs: 1370251787
    nsecs: 143330097
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -1.01842431067
      y: -0.000323505793659
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.00046593365865
      w: 0.999999891453
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -7.04065560314
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -1.12850912872
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Thank you for reading and any hint to solve the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64196/move_base-problem/) by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-06-19**:
Please post results from view frames (http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Debugging%20tools#view_frames) and the move_base params yaml files.

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-06-20**:
Hi Weiin, I posted the files and a link below. It would be great, if you can give me hint, where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few things I noticed that may be causing your problem. Your velocity (twist in odom topic) seems quite high (-7m/s?). This does not match what you put in the yaml file (max_vel_x: 0.5). I suggest you review your calculation for the velocity and do a teleop check on your robot. eg, command robot to move at 0.1m/s. Check if odom twist gives 0.1m/s

You mentioned in your question you are using amcl. But the frames show /odom_map_broadcaster broadcasting map->odom. I suggest you read through http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials to understand how to set up your robot for autonomous navigation

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-07-04**:
Hi, weiin, thanks for your answer. the error was a missing decimal point in my footprint. What do you mean with your last sentence? Can you please explain to use amcl? The right frames? thx

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-07-04**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl amcl is just a method for localization within a known map. You mentioned using it in your question. But you are also using odom_map_broadcaster to broadcast a static transform. So you need to figure out what you really want. Reading through that tutorial will help.

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2013-07-05**:
Hi weiin, I believe that I understood the navigation-tutorials. I mentioned AMCL, because I was not sure where the error was. When I understand it right, I start AMCL on top, but dont have to create a transform manually?

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-07-07**:
yes, with amcl, you will not need the static transform /map->/odom